# Why can't it read ID3 tags from an external server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, id3

I am trying to read a ID3 tags on a mp3 file from an external server, but it does not work correctly and in console the following error is given:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/music.mp3. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Here is my code: **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hoycxwsh/)**

```js
 var filename = "https://rjmediamusic.com/media/mp3/mp3-256/Alireza-JJ-Sijal-Nassim-Ki-Khoobe-Ki-Bad-(Ft-Behzad-Leito-Sami-Low-AFX).mp3";
 ID3.loadTags(filename, function() {
   var tags = ID3.getAllTags(filename);
   alert(tags.artist + " - " + tags.title + ", " + tags.album);
 });
```

```html
<script src="http://web.ist.utl.pt/antonio.afonso/www.aadsm.net/libraries/id3/scripts/id3-minimized.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea how I can solve this. I do not have access to the server so I can not make any modification, I only stream music from there.

Comment: You're hitting the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: @joews Thanks for your comment, so as far as I understood it is only possible if the music provide server permits me to grab ID3 data, otherwise I cannot do anything. right?

Comment: You could also proxy the requests through a server that you own, but changing the ID3 server to set CORS headers is a better solution.